# Android SDK platforms between Linux and Windows

Tags: android

I'm dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 Linux. Can I just copy my existing Android SDK platforms from my windows partition to the linux partition? Or are the platforms different? I don't want to waste time redownloading all the packages again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android SDK is platform-dependent.
Check this: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 21):

Android SDK is platform-dependent. That is right.

But if you want to spare some space, you can share several folders between the two OS. You can link Windows folders in Linux using something like `ln -s /media/Windows/sdk/XXX ./XXX` for the following independent platform folders :

- extras
- platforms
- samples
- sources
- system-images

Then launch the Android SDK on Linux `./tools/android` and check if the packages are available or if some are broken.

Comment: SDK update mechanism is broken then; it doesn't support symlinks

Answer (score 8):

although i have setup a virtual machine to do android developement but [metch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18332984/817029)  is right. it worked for me.

i used bash script with following code to do the symbolic linking

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -s /home/user/software/sdk/extras /home/user/work/sdk/
ln -s /home/user/software/sdk/platforms /home/user/work/sdk/
ln -s /home/user/software/sdk/samples /home/user/work/sdk/
ln -s /home/user/software/sdk/sources /home/user/work/sdk/
ln -s /home/user/software/sdk/system-images /home/user/work/sdk/
```

Answer (score 5):

The list of folders that you can share between Linux & Windows file system as they are the same files for Android SDK are below. You can just copy & paste these folders between any OS you use:

**add-ons,
docs,
extras,
ndk-bundle,
platforms,
skins,
sources,
system-images,
tools**

Apparently, you will need to download the below folders i.e. SDK Tools differently for each OS, as they are platform dependent tools which rely upon OS like Linux, Windows & Mac OS differently:

**build-tools,
platform-tools**

These two folders don't eat up much of a download bandwidth. So you can easily download it as per the OS you are working on.

I have tested and tried this successfully so far and all worked well with full support. This will save a lot of disk space as well as download bandwidth & time for sure!

Answer (score 1):

well,There are some difference and some simliarity,the folder platforms,platforms-tools,samples,sources can be shared and they are the largest files

you can link these four folders to linux`s sdk folder

```
ln -s /mnt/path/to/your/windows/sdk/* /home/youname/yourAndroidBundle/sdk/
```