# Is the android SDK different for windows and ubuntu (not android studio just the sdk-system images build tools etc)

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I am shifting from `windows` to `ubuntu`. I have downloaded `ANDROID STUDIO` for `ubuntu` but do I also have to install a new `SDK` or i can use the `windows` version(`build tools`, `platform images` ...etc).

I want to avoid downloading GB's of `build tools`, `platform tools` , `play services`, etc.

Comment: you can use the same

Comment: you should download Android SDK on ubuntu. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK platforms between Linux and Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792078/android-sdk-platforms-between-linux-and-windows)

Answer (score 4):

The binaries within the Windows version of the SDK will not work on Linux. Since the two operating systems have different executable formats and different core libraries, the executables in the Windows version won't run on Linux.

There are some things you can copy over - for instance you'll most likely be able to copy over the system-images folder within the SDK, as this contains the disk images used within the emulator. This might be the same for some of the other folders, I'm not sure though.

Comment: yes I found a lot of executables in build tools folders in my windows version...obviously now i need a sdk for linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install sdk again for ubuntu OS, I once tried to add windows android sdk and found it not working.
It may be because of different os architecture.

[link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)!

May be that's why google provide different file for mac, windows & Linux 
I hope this helps.

Comment: ur link has android studio for linux but no mention for sdk for linux

Comment: the link for android sdk is available on same page (scroll down)

Comment: or u can download sdk while installing android studio using your internet in case u dont want to download sdk seprately

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a new SDK, windows version is incompatible with linux.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK is platform-dependent. Below discussions and links are helpful,

[Android SDK platforms between Linux and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792078/android-sdk-platforms-between-linux-and-windows)

and [Are there dfferences between the Windows and Linux versions of the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039529/are-there-dfferences-between-the-windows-and-linux-versions-of-the-android-sdk)

Hope this is helpful.