# Using same Android-sdk in Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, android-studio

Hello Is it possible to share android sdk for both Linux and windows' android studio ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK platforms between Linux and Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792078/android-sdk-platforms-between-linux-and-windows)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean sharing it between dual boot on the same pc? If so I would say no since windows can't access linux files.

If you mean you want to download the same version for both then yes why wouldn't you be able to ?

Comment: No not just because Windows can't access linux FS, but because SDK contains platform-dependent binaries

Comment: I was giving one of the reasons